# Powershell: How to get the average of numbers after ";" symbol? (from a txt file)

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a txt file of students and their grades splitted with ";" syimbol.

like this

```
Andrea Pirlo; 5 4 5 4 5 4
Alessandro Del Piero; 5 3 4
Gianluigi Buffon; 4 4 3 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

I need to count the number of their grades and the average their grades. I got the number of grades, it works right but I can't get any output for the average.

```
$file = file.txt
$file | ForEach-Object{
    if(($_.split(';')[1].split() | Measure-Object).Count -gt 5){
        Write-Host (($_.split(';')[1].split() | Measure-Object).Count)
        Write-Host (($_.split(';')[1].split() | Measure-Object).Average)
    }
}
```

I don't understand because the two lines are just about the same.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Change the last `Measure-Object` call to `Measure-Object -Average`

Comment: It works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at 'Description' section in documentation:  [link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7.1#description)

If you don't pass any argument, it would give you only count property.

You have to add `-Average` to your command e.g.

(1,2,3,4,5 | Measure-Object -Average).Average  <-- that command will return correct value 3

Comment: It works after adding -Average, thank you!